# Launch Multiple Instances of Shell scripts in Parallel

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, script

I have a **parent folder** which contains a script **mytestcase.sh**

```
 Parent_folder/mytestcase.sh
```

I would like to launch 5 terminal instances to run mytestcase.sh from 5 different terminals at the same time after copying the Parent folder 5 times and then launching the mytestcase.sh from its folder directory. The reason I am copying the folder 5 times is because the script opens and writes to several files and I dont want multiple scripts to write to same file .

Ex:

```
Terminal1 : Copy Parent folder and launch: Parent_folder_copy1/mytestcase.sh
Terminal2 : Copy Parent folder and launch: Parent_folder_copy2/mytestcase.sh
Terminal3 : Copy Parent folder and launch: Parent_folder_copy3/mytestcase.sh
Terminal4 : Copy Parent folder and launch: Parent_folder_copy4/mytestcase.sh
Terminal5 : Copy Parent folder and launch: Parent_folder_copy5/mytestcase.sh
```

How can achieve this from a shell script ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve or test? This kind of sounds like you're testing parallel processing… but by a method that will be bottlenecked by disk i/o speed, hence give distorted results.

Comment: Thats correct. I am trying to test parallel processing ,. The test cases access low level hardware and we are interested to see the multi-instance test case commands behavior on the Hardware.

Comment: OK, no worries - if you're actually trying to see where it will bottleneck, then it will bottleneck at disk i/o. No testing necessary ;) It looks like the kind of process that just doesn't benefit form parallelism at all.

Comment: Yes. I am really struck on shell script to achieve the desired output. We arent assessing anything other than running parallel instances.